# What is archive mode in rsync?

Tags: rsync

I know you can use `-a` or `--archive` to activate archive mode when using rsync. Unfortunately, I have no idea what archive mode is supposed to do, and the man page is not at all explicit about what this is:

> equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)

Can you explain what those options (`rlptgoD`) mean and what's the behaviour of rsync when I use them?

Comment: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rsync%20-rlptgoD

Answer (score 343):

It's all of these:

> `-r`, `--recursive`             recurse into directories
>
> `-l`, `--links`                 copy symlinks as symlinks
>
> `-p`, `--perms`                 preserve permissions
>
> `-t`, `--times`                 preserve modification times
>
> `-g`, `--group`                 preserve group
>
> `-o`, `--owner`                 preserve owner (super-user only)
>
> `-D`                          same as `--devices --specials`
>
> `--devices`               preserve device files (super-user only)
>
> `--specials`              preserve special files

It excludes:

> `-H`, `--hard-links`            preserve hard links
>
> `-A`, `--acls`                  preserve ACLs (implies `-p`)
>
> `-X`, `--xattrs`                preserve extended attributes

It's perfect for backups. My "default" set of switches is `-avzP` - archive mode, be verbose, use compression, preserve partial files, display progress.

Note: Invariably when the descriptions say "preserve", it means make the destination be like the source.

Comment: +1 - yes, it's in the man page, but it's also nice to see it here with the answer for easy reference

Comment: easier than looking in the man page :P ?

Comment: +1 for sharing the option combination for backups (-avzP).

Comment: yeah somewhere along the way, lmgtfy became easier than man rsync.

Comment: eh.. could someone point which option of `-avzP` is for partial files? Isn't it `--partial`, without a short version? (`rsync 3.1.0`)

Comment: @xealits According to the man page, `The -P option is equivalent to --partial --progress.`

Comment: If you're not rsyncing to a remote server (user@server:/../..) `-z` and `-P` might slow things down without adding much benefit... I've noticed some performance gains when rsyncing locally...

Comment: @Salami I have searched through the whole man page, there is no accumulated listing like that in there - you would have to look up each option individually, which is a jump-back-and-forth-hassle.

Comment: For all of those suggesting that we should just `man` stuff like this - `man`'s UX is vastly inferior to a modern web browser. It works, but I feel no shame Googling first.

Comment: For the interested, his default set of switches equates to

`--archive --verbose --compress --progress`

Comment: Except that... it's not recursive. `rsync` 3.2.7 on Ubuntu 22.04, I have to add `r` to `aviXPz` to make it recurse; no idea why. I've got old `rsync` scripts going back to Centos 6 where I had to do the same thing. Maybe the `X` confuses it.

Answer (score 24):

It make sure the permission, attributes, etc. is same at the both side. rsync only works in that way... if you want to synchronising files, you have to use -a parameter.

This is because rsync compare these permission, attribute, etc. at both side to determining if they are the *SAME FILE* and decide if it should be updated. if you use rsync -r xxx yyy instead rsync -a xxx yyy, some files will be copy again and again, coz, permission, attribute not be synchronised, and miss matched at both side...

Answer (score 18):

The archive switch is just a shortcut to skip having to enter a bunch of switches that you'll normally use if you're using rsync to make backups (a common task).

It's the same as typing:

```
rsync -r -l -p -t -g -o -D
```

And it's much easier to remember.  You can find definitions for all of those switches in the man page.

(The hyphens are optional when you're combining multiple single-letter switches.)

Comment: thanks, but I think you're missing my point. Can you please explain what combining all those options does without having me read 7 different parts of the man page, which probably refer to other parts of the man page?

Comment: I think you're missing the point that it's important to read the man page to know exactly what you're doing.  rsync has some very powerful options, including a way to delete files!  It's like your asking for help on using a table saw because you don't like reading instruction manuals.

Comment: Of course, I just don't like reading the instruction manual for the 100th time when I can instead refer to a cheatsheet.