# rsync encounters chgrp errors despite --no-g

Tags: rsync, usb, permissions, chgrp

I am using rsync to sync a directory to a USB-mounted device. That device automounts with `myuser:root` ownership. When I rsync my directory (that has `myuser:myuser` ownership) with `-a`, I get many of the following errors:

```
rsync: chgrp "filename" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
```

I tried adding `--no-g` after the `-a` option (since in this case I don't care about setting the group), but the errors persist. What do I need to do to stop rsync from trying to `chgrp` everything?

Comment: What filesystem is on the device?

Comment: @Andrew: It's vfat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[FAT does not have permissions](http://edge-op.org/grouch/fatperm.html); you could try either re-mounting the device with different owner/group/umask, or expanding [the archive flag](https://serverfault.com/questions/141773/what-is-archive-mode-in-rsync) and removing

- "preserve permissions" flag `-p`
- "preserve groups" flag `-g`
- "preserve symlinks" flag `-l`
- "preserve special & device files" flag `-D`

Essentially `rsync -rt` is good enough for a FAT target.

The lazy option would be `sudo rsync -a $target $dest 2> /dev/null` (run as root to try and force the group change, ignore error messages).